# How do i remove the List type property name and the {} and [] brackets while serialing in C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json-serialization

this is the model I'm Serialzing

```
    public class SomeClassOne
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public List<Location> locations { get; set; }
        public string DOB { get; set; }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }

    }

    public class Location
    {
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string PinCode { get; set; }
    }
```

> /and i'm assigning values to that model properties

```
    public List<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        List<Product> Products = new List<Product>();
        string[] codes = { "Code-A", "Code-B", "Code-C","Code-D", "Code-E" };
        foreach (var cod in codes)
        {
            Product product = new Product();
            product.Code = cod;
            Products.Add(product);
        }
        return Products;
    }

    public List<SomeClassOne> someClss()
    {
        List<SomeClassOne> someCls = new List<SomeClassOne();
        SomeClassOne classOne = new SomeClassOne();
        someCls.Add(classOne);
        classOne.Products = GetProducts();

        return someCls;
    }

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someClss(), Formatting.Indented);
   
    Console.WriteLine(json);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

the generated Json is as below

```
[
  {
    "name": null,
    "Gender": null,
    "Age": 0,
    "Products": [
      {
        "Code": "Code-A",
        "Price": null
      },
      {
        "Code": "Code-B",
        "Price": null
      },
      {
        "Code": "Code-C",
        "Price": null
      },
      {
        "Code": "Code-D",
        "Price": null
      },
      {
        "Code": "Code-E",
        "Price": null
      }
    ],
    "locations": null,
    "DOB": null
  }
]
```

how can i remove the {} [] and and generate the Json as below after serialization

```
 [
          {
            "Code": "Code-A",
            "Price": null
          },
          {
            "Code": "Code-B",
            "Price": null
          },
          {
            "Code": "Code-C",
            "Price": null
          },
          {
            "Code": "Code-D",
            "Price": null
          },
          {
            "Code": "Code-E",
            "Price": null
          }
    ]
```

Any one please help me i have seen some Contract Resolver and did not find any solution, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is very hard to understand, but it looks like you just need to serialise an instance of `List<Product>` and forget about the rest.

Comment: Working with json library you just have to get Product result: `returnvalue['Products']`

Comment: @DavidG yes this List<Product> is in the SomeClassOne and this some class

Comment: Yes, I'm saying you should be serialising the result of `GetProducts()` and forgetting the rest.

Comment: @DavidG actually this SomeClassOne is again a List type property in a different class and these are part of a bigger class which i'm actually serializing and so how do i achieve this in that case.

Comment: as far as I understand, you don't need to return the list in `public List<SomeClassOne> someClss()` as you are adding only one item to the list, if you return only one you will get rid out of the []

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var products=GetProducts();

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(products, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

    Console.WriteLine(json);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

json

```
[
  {
    "Code": "Code-A",
    "Price": null
  },
  {
    "Code": "Code-B",
    "Price": null
  },
  {
    "Code": "Code-C",
    "Price": null
  },
  {
    "Code": "Code-D",
    "Price": null
  },
  {
    "Code": "Code-E",
    "Price": null
  }
]
```